# How to send response to watson assistant from node.js

Tags: node.js, watson-conversation

I would like to send response to watson assistant from node.js application.
After the registration of the complaint data in the database, a message will be sent to the customer: Your claim number ... has been registered.
Currently, the requested data is stored in the database but the response is not sent.
The code is:

---

```
function updateMessage(input, response) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var responseText = null;  
        var a = response.intents;
        a.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
        if (entry.intent==="Confirmer")
        {         
            // console.log(response);
            console.log(response.context);

            var num_contrat = response.context.num_contrat;
            var compagnie = response.context.compagnie;
            var prenom = response.context.prenom;
            var nom = response.context.nom;
            var obj_reclamation = response.context.obj_reclamation;
            obj_reclamation = obj_reclamation.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
            nom = nom.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');

            con.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Connecté !");
                var sql = "INSERT INTO reclamation (num_contrat, compagnie, nom, prenom, reclamation_mot_justif) VALUES ('"+num_contrat+"', '"+compagnie+"','"+nom+"','"+prenom+"','"+obj_reclamation+"')";
                con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                        console.log("1 enregistrement a été inséré dans la base de donnée");
                        console.log("ID = ",result.insertId); // dernier ID inséré
                        responseText = "Votre réclamation N° " + result.insertId +" a été bien enregistrée.";
                        console.log("responseText = ", responseText);
                        response.output.text = responseText;
                        console.log("response.output.text = ", response.output.text);
                        console.log(response);
                        //response.output.text.push(responseText);
                        resolve(response);
                    });       
                });             
            }
        });


      if (!response.output) {
      response.output = {};
    } else if (response.intents[0] === undefined) {
      resolve(response);
    }       

      else if (response.intents[0].intent === "discovery" || response.output.text == '' ) {

      responseText = sendToDiscovery(input.input.text);
      responseText.then(function(responseText) { 
          response.output.text = responseText;       
         resolve(response);
      });
    } else {
      resolve(response);
    }
  });
}
```

---

Thanks.

Comment: Please add mor details. It is not clear what you or your code is doing and where it is executed.

Comment: Taking the example of "Submit a complaint": After the confirmation of the requested data (contract number, company, surname, first name and claim) (=> intent #confirm), they will be recorded in the DB, and the message that must be returned is: "Your complaint N ° ... has been registered." (This allows customer to track his claim through this number). At the cmd console, the result output.text = "Your claim N° ... has been successfully recorded." On the other hand, the result at the interface of the application is the one introduced in the service assistant "Your complaint was well recorded"